# Stratego/XT Programming Language

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

Does anyone know something about [Stratego/XT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratego/XT) Programming Language? What is it good for? Any good and/or bad experiences with it? Any real live running example?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stratego/XT is a language and toolset for program transformation based on term rewriting with programmable rewriting strategies.

You can find documentation and scientific papers about language and toolset at http://strategoxt.org.

A real life application of Stratego/XT is WebDSL (webdsl.org), a domain-specific language for the development of web applications, which in turn has been used to build researchr.org.

Stratego/XT is also the basis for the Spoofax/IMP toolset for building Eclipse IDE plugins for custom (domain-specific) languages (see Spoofax-IMP page on stratego site).

Answer (score 1):

Try [TXL](http://txl.ca) instead. It is easier to start with and does the similar jobs. There are examples on its site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in Stratego (or TXL), you are likely to be interested in the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).

DMS is a full-featured program transformation system that at its core offers source-to-source rewrites, like Stratego and TXL.  And you can use that to implement your own custom DSL compiler, or mass source code change engine.

Where DMS is different is that it can be obtained with tested-by-fire front ends for Java, C#, C++, C and COBOL, most of which will parse your source code, build ASTs and symbol tables, and for several of these provide control-flow, data-flow and points to analyzers.
The analysis infrastructure is generic, and can be used on your DSLs, too.

You can find a comparison of these systems at the web site.